# Interpreting the output when using --startuptime

Tags: startup

When I use the `--startuptime <file>` option, `vim` generates an output file. I've included an example at the bottom of this post.

How can I interpret the output? I can't find documentation to verify my assumptions (I checked `:help startuptime`).

The preamble suggests that lines are of one of two forms:

1. `clock   self+sourced   self:  sourced script`
2. `clock   elapsed:              other lines`

Interpreting *form 1* lines seems straightforward, with times corresponding to the described event. However, I'm not sure what exactly is meant by `other lines` (assuming I've interpreted the preamble correctly).

For the *form 2* lines, what are the definitions of `self+sourced` and `self`? I have assumed the former corresponds to loading time *including* time for recursively `:source`'d files, and the latter corresponds to loading time *excluding* time for recursively `:source`'d files.

What does the `sourcing vimrc file(s)` line's time represent? There is a separate line for `$HOME/.vimrc`, with a time greater than given for `sourcing vimrc file(s)`.

Similarly, what does the `loading plugins` line's time represent? The preceding lines also correspond to plugins, and the sum of the times does not match the `loading plugins` time.

Example:

```
times in msec
 clock   self+sourced   self:  sourced script
 clock   elapsed:              other lines

000.011  000.011: --- VIM STARTING ---
000.149  000.138: Allocated generic buffers
000.757  000.608: locale set
000.761  000.004: clipboard setup
000.770  000.009: window checked
001.565  000.795: inits 1
001.577  000.012: parsing arguments
001.578  000.001: expanding arguments
012.666  011.088: shell init
013.157  000.491: Termcap init
013.174  000.017: inits 2
013.360  000.186: init highlight
015.671  001.128  001.128: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/syntax/syncolor.vim
015.851  001.490  000.362: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/syntax/synload.vim
023.584  007.559  007.559: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/filetype.vim
023.644  009.518  000.469: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/syntax/syntax.vim
023.810  000.024  000.024: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/filetype.vim
023.968  000.021  000.021: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/filetype.vim
024.170  000.056  000.056: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/ftplugin.vim
024.326  000.021  000.021: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/filetype.vim
024.524  000.056  000.056: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/indent.vim
025.633  011.850  002.154: sourcing $HOME/.vimrc
025.641  000.431: sourcing vimrc file(s)
026.743  000.087  000.087: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
027.089  000.265  000.265: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/plugin/gzip.vim
027.499  000.326  000.326: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/plugin/logiPat.vim
027.651  000.050  000.050: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/plugin/manpager.vim
027.965  000.234  000.234: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/plugin/matchparen.vim
028.739  000.692  000.692: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
028.956  000.038  000.038: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/plugin/rrhelper.vim
029.179  000.093  000.093: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/plugin/spellfile.vim
029.526  000.228  000.228: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
029.757  000.135  000.135: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/plugin/tohtml.vim
030.055  000.211  000.211: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
030.379  000.219  000.219: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
031.020  000.382  000.382: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/pack/dist/opt/matchit/plugin/matchit.vim
032.073  000.812  000.812: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/pack/dist/opt/termdebug/plugin/termdebug.vim
032.081  002.668: loading plugins
032.198  000.117: loading packages
032.245  000.047: loading after plugins
032.251  000.006: inits 3
041.476  009.225: reading viminfo
041.548  000.072: setting raw mode
041.556  000.008: start termcap
041.574  000.018: clearing screen
041.684  000.110: opening buffers
041.745  000.061: BufEnter autocommands
041.751  000.006: editing files in windows
042.152  000.401: VimEnter autocommands
042.154  000.002: before starting main loop
043.052  000.898: first screen update
043.054  000.002: --- VIM STARTED ---
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I interpret the output? I can't find documentation to verify my assumptions (I checked :help startuptime).

See just below [`:h :profd`](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#:profd):

> You must always start with a ":profile start fname" command.  The resulting
>   file is written when Vim exits.  Here is an example of the output, with line
>   numbers prepended for the explanation:
>
> ```
>   1 FUNCTION  Test2() ~
>   2 Called 1 time ~
>   3 Total time:   0.155251 ~
>   4  Self time:   0.002006 ~
>   5  ~
>   6 count  total (s)   self (s) ~
>   7   9          0.000096   for i in range(8) ~
>   8   8   0.153655   0.000410     call Test3() ~
>   9   8          0.000070   endfor ~
>  10                 " Ask a question ~
>  11   1          0.001341   echo input("give me an answer: ") ~
> ```
>
> The header (lines 1-4) gives the time for the whole function.  The "Total"
>   time is the time passed while the function was executing.  The "Self" time is
>   the "Total" time reduced by time spent in:
>
> - other user defined functions
> - sourced scripts
> - executed autocommands
> - external (shell) commands
>
> Lines 7-11 show the time spent in each executed line.  Lines that are not
>   executed do not count.  Thus a comment line is never counted.
>
> The Count column shows how many times a line was executed.  Note that the
>   "for" command in line 7 is executed one more time as the following lines.
>   That is because the line is also executed to detect the end of the loop.
>
> The time Vim spends waiting for user input isn't counted at all.  Thus how
>   long you take to respond to the input() prompt is irrelevant.
>
> Profiling should give a good indication of where time is spent, but keep in
>   mind there are various things that may clobber the results:
>
> - The accuracy of the time measured depends on the gettimeofday() system
>     function.  It may only be as accurate as 1/100 second, even though the times
>     are displayed in micro seconds.
> - Real elapsed time is measured, if other processes are busy they may cause
>     delays at unpredictable moments.  You may want to run the profiling several
>     times and use the lowest results.
> - If you have several commands in one line you only get one time.  Split the
>     line to see the time for the individual commands.
> - The time of the lines added up is mostly less than the time of the whole
>     function.  There is some overhead in between.
> - Functions that are deleted before Vim exits will not produce profiling
>     information.  You can check the |v:profiling| variable if needed: >
>         :if !v:profiling
>         :   delfunc MyFunc
>         :endif
>     <
> - Profiling may give weird results on multi-processor systems, when sleep
>     mode kicks in or the processor frequency is reduced to save power.
> - The "self" time is wrong when a function is used recursively.

---

> The preamble suggests that lines are of one of two forms:
>
> ```
> clock   self+sourced   self:  sourced script
> clock   elapsed:              other lines
> ```
>
> Interpreting form 1 lines seems straightforward, with times corresponding to the described event. However, I'm not sure what exactly is meant by other lines (assuming I've interpreted the preamble correctly).

There are 2 types of lines in the output; those with 4 fields:

```
015.671  001.128       001.128:  sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/syntax/syncolor.vim
^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^       ^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
field 1  field 2       field 3   field 4
clock    self+sourced  self:     sourced script
```

And those with 3 fields:

```
000.149  000.138:  Allocated generic buffers
^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
field 1  field 2   field 3
clock    elapsed   other lines
```

"other lines" refers to the third field in lines with only 3 fields.

---

> For the form 2 lines, what are the definitions of self+sourced and self? I have assumed the former corresponds to loading time including time for recursively :source'd files, and the latter corresponds to loading time excluding time for recursively :source'd files.

If `self` has the same meaning as in the output of `:prof start`, it's documented like this:

> The "Self" time is the "Total" time reduced by time spent in:
>
> - other user defined functions
> - sourced scripts
> - executed autocommands
> - external (shell) commands

---

> What does the sourcing vimrc file(s) line's time represent? There is a separate line for $HOME/.vimrc, with a time greater than given for sourcing vimrc file(s).

Just a guess, but it may be the time taken by Vim to find the vimrc file on your system...
If you want to look at the source code, the relevant line is [here](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/28e4c8d9f0e976dfa05b2ea97cfbe926f88d403c/src/main.c#L2706).

---

> Similarly, what does the loading plugins line's time represent? The preceding lines also correspond to plugins, and the sum of the times does not match the loading plugins time.

Again, just a guess, but it may be the time taken by Vim to find all your plugin files on your system (i.e. all the files in your runtime path matching the glob `plugin/**/*.vim`)...
If you want to look at the source code, the relevant line is [here](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/28e4c8d9f0e976dfa05b2ea97cfbe926f88d403c/src/main.c#L568).